# Where can I find the detailed manual page for gpg --list-secret-keys output

Tags: pgp, gnupg

I get confused about the terms used in the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`

For example what is the meaning of following:

`sec` `sec#` `ssb`  `ssb>`

there are many codes being used in the output. Can anyone point to the official docs where everything is explained?

I found this [link](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r786.html) but nothing is explained there.

Answer (score 8):

Another info source is the [DETAILS](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/doc/DETAILS) file in the [GnuPG distribution](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg).

Section ["Field 1 - Type of record"](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/doc/DETAILS#field-1---type-of-record) states

```
Field 1 - Type of record

pub
Public key

crt
X.509 certificate

crs
X.509 certificate and private key available

sub
Subkey (secondary key)

sec
Secret key

ssb
Secret subkey (secondary key)

uid
User id

uat
User attribute (same as user id except for field 10).

sig
Signature

rev
Revocation signature

rvs
Revocation signature (standalone) [since 2.2.9]

fpr
Fingerprint (fingerprint is in field 10)

pkd
Public key data [*]

grp
Keygrip

rvk
Revocation key

tfs
TOFU statistics [*]

tru
Trust database information [*]

spk
Signature subpacket [*]

cfg
Configuration data [*]

Records marked with an asterisk are described at *Special fields.
```

Answer (score 6):

- [sec] - The following is a secret key
- [ssb] - The following is a secret ***sub*** key

The meaning of # after each of these is that the key is not usable, if say, you used the export subkeys option or if the key is otherwise taken "offline".

The meaning of > is that the key is stored on something like a smart card.

You can find more info here at [Ubuntu's man page for GPG](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/gpg.1.html)
and the documentation you reference has been moved to [here at GnuPG.org](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there place where I can see the detailed description of these codes? I couldn't find anything on both the urls you mentioned. I searched for 'ssb'

Comment: @zaphod TBH I think the gnupg documentation is still lacking. Probably because they are moving to a new documentation format (which in the open source community can take a while). **However** I remembered a great walk-through by void. You can find it here: https://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2013/12/02/creating-a-new-gpg-key-with-subkeys/  Read up on this and by the end you'll get it all. It should do in place of the documentation until they get that going again. The only thing it doesn't discuss is > which only means the key you are listing is on a device like a smartcard or usbkey or something.

Comment: I asked about the official docs at https://dev.gnupg.org/T1563#122298

Answer (score 1):

Based on in the information I have gathered:

On using command `gpg -K` which lists secret keys:

`sec`: the master/primary secret key. There is key size, keyid, creation date, expiration date and fingerprint information displayed.

`ssb`: secret subkeys. These can be your sub signing key, encryption key or authentication key. You can have multiple subkeys.

`uid`: this is the user information associated with the secret key. You can have multiple uids.

`sec#`: # after sec means that your secret key is missing from the machine. But it has a reference to the secret key.

`ssb>`: > after ssb means that your subkeys are not the machine. Instead they are on a smartcard.

On using command `gpg -k` which lists public keys:

`pub`: your public key info.

`sub`: your public subkey info.

If you have any other information which is missing. Please edit the answer or leave a comment.

Thanks to @Nalaurien for the previous answer.